# Discrete subsets in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

[image]

So this is the first time I have seen the definition for a "discrete" subset. I want to first make sure that my understanding is correct. If $D$ is discrete, then D is essentially just the boundary of say, a circle, but the interior is not in D, it's just the boundary. So D could be $D := \{ |z| = 1 | z \in \mathbb{C}\}$ and this is a discrete subset, correct?

Comment: May I ask which book are these problem from? It seems instructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A discrete set defined hereby is essentially a formalisation of the general notion of discreteness we have used so soften. The set $\{1, 2, 3, ..\}$ is discrete in the sense that there are "gaps" between any element in the set and all other elements in the set.

Defining this using balls: If $D$ is a discrete subset of $\Bbb C$. Then there is an open ball centered at every element $z$ of $D$ such that the only element in the said ball is $z$. This is your definition in English.

As for the first part of your problem: $\Bbb Z$ is discrete in $\Bbb R$ since you can take balls with any radius less than $1$ and the only element in the said ball will be its centre.  Same cannot be said about $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$. The set $\{\frac 1 n \ | \ n \in \Bbb N\}$ is discrete too. Since suppose $\frac 1 m $ is an arbitrary element in it. $ \frac {1}{m + 1} \lt \frac {1}{m } \lt \frac {1}{m - 1} $. You can pick a ball centred at $\frac 1 m$ with radius $r  = \text{Min} \{ \frac {1}{m } - \frac {1}{m + 1}, \frac {1}{m - 1} - \frac {1}{m } \}$. Every finite set too is discrete. The proof is slightly long. Drop a comment if you need it.

---

**Update:** To prove that every finite set is discrete; Suppose there is a finite set $X$ which is not discrete. Then there is an element $z \in X$ such that every open ball centered at $z$ contains an element in $X$ distinct from $z$. Let $r_1 \gt 0$ be arbitrary. $\exists z_1 (\neq z) \in X$ such that $|z_1 - z| \lt r_1$. Let $r_2 = |z_1 - z| \gt 0$. then $\exists z_2(\neq z) \in X$ such that $|z_2 - z| \lt r_2$. Let $r_3 = |z_2 - z| \gt 0$. Continuing in this fashion we can create an infinite subset $\{z_1, z_2, ..., z_n, ..\}$ of $X$ which is infinite leading to a contradiction.

---

My knowledge on continuous functions is pitiful so I have to skip problems (ii) and (iii).

But let's get to (iv).

$D$ is discrete and compact. For every element $x \in D$ there is an open ball $B(x)$ centred at $x$ such that $B(x) = \{x\}$. Then $\bigcup_{x \in D} B(x) \supseteq D$ which is an open covering of $D$. So there is a finite collection of balls of the form $B(x)$ for $x \in D$ such that there union contains $D$. It follows $D$ is finite.

Like I said just picture a discrete probability distribution if you will. The elements in the set have "gaps" between them. This is how you picture it, I think. Your comprehension I'm afraid is completely flawed. Since the definition of a boundary of a set $D$ implies each one of its neighbourhoods (including all open balls) contain elements of $D$ and $D^C$.

**Footnote:** The idea of gaps between elements does not always work, I just realised. $\Bbb Q$ is not discrete but there are gaps in it. Maybe by gaps you need to understand that there is a definite *"distance"* between an element in a discrete set and all other elements in it.

Comment: Wow, your definition really cleared up my understanding, thank you so much.. I will start working on the problems soon and look at your answer more closely :)

Comment: @Glad to help. And hats off for trying them on your own.

Comment: after reading your footnote: the idea of "gaps" as you've said in a discrete set can be more or less related back to the natural numbers it seems? where the distance between each element and it's successor is always the same, 1.

Comment: @terrible at math: i Guess. But the definition here is a lot more general. For instance the distance is not uniform. It can vary. A discrete set can be bounded, like $\{\frac 1 n\}$. I should also say that I am very much an amateur and had not heard of a discrete set before so formulate your own pictures and ideas and take my word for less than dime, yes?

Comment: Understood, thanks anyways, your answer is still very helpful.

The first is very clear, $\mathbb{Z}$ is definitely discrete in $\mathbb{R}$ -- just take a ball around some integer of $0 < r < 1$ and we can see it only intersects at the integer.

Comment: It also makes perfect sense that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not discrete in $\mathbb{R}$. This is more or less due to the fact that there is always a neighborhood of rational numbers around every irrational number.

Comment: thank you for all of this. I am now on the last set of part (i), any finite set D. You don't have to write a whole proof for me lol, just give me a hint or so, what do I know about elements of D?

Comment: Also, the set of $\frac{1}{n}$ union $0$ is discrete I said, since we already showed that everything but 0 is okay and $\frac{1}{n}$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$ so it makes sense.

Comment: Suppose to the contrary there is a finite set $D$ in $\Bbb C$ which is not discrete. Pick an arbitrary element in it $x$. Every open ball centred at $x$ must contain an element in $D$ unequal to $x$. Try to argue then that $D$ cannot be finite..

Comment: @terrible at math: With reference to $\{\frac 1 n \} \cup \{0\}$ Not so fast. Is there an open ball centred at $0$ such that $0$  is the only element in it?

Comment: Actually no, I don't think so... which by the same logic I used above makes more sense this way... since the "density" of the elements increases around 0..

Comment: Thank you for showing me the error of my previous thinking with regards to that union :) The definition of a discrete set is truly becoming clearer as I work more with this.

I am trying to apply your strategy for any finite set, and it is more or less coming together -- I may not know a sufficient argument for an infinite set though. Since we must have that an open ball around $x$ for ALL $r > 0$ contains a non-$x$ element, it implies that there is non-$x$ element arbitrarily close to $x$ for all $x \in D$.  It's just like an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ but I don't know how to formalize it.

Comment: @terrible at math: Sorry for the late response. Was at work. Not getting your question. Are you having trouble proving that every finite set is discrete or are you asking for a sufficient condition for an infinite set to be discrete?

Comment: The first, but only because I am having trouble wrapping it up. Read this part: "ince we must have that an open ball around x for ALL r>0 contains a non-x element, it implies that there is non-x element arbitrarily close to x for all x∈D. It's just like an open interval in R but I don't know how to formalize it"

Comment: @terrible at math: I updated the answer.

Comment: @terrible at math: Anytime.